# Terraform - Passing type Object as a parameter to Azure Template Deployment

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am tying to to provision Azure AD Domain Service using Terraform by giving Terraform the Azure ARM template, this is because Terrafrom does not support provisioning Azure AD Domain Service natively.

I have exported the ARM Template and it's parameters, one of the parameters is called `"notificationSettings"` which is a type `Object` and looks like below :

```
    "notificationSettings": {
        "value": {
            "notifyGlobalAdmins": "Enabled",
            "notifyDcAdmins": "Enabled",
            "additionalRecipients": []
        }
    }
```

Other parameters are all `strings` and I can pass them without any issue, for example:

```
"apiVersion" = "2017-06-01"
```

I have tried passing this object to parameters like below :

```
"notificationSettings" = [{
                "notifyGlobalAdmins" = "Enabled"
            "notifyDcAdmins" ="Enabled"
            "additionalRecipients" = []
}]
```

However, when I execute `terrafrom apply`, terrafrom complains and say:

> Inappropriate value for attribute "parameters": element
>   "notificationSettings": string required.

How do I pass parameters type of Object to `template body`?

I have also tried giving the entire ARM json parameter as a file to terrafrom by using `parameters_body` option like below :

```
parameters_body = "${file("${path.module}/temp/params.json")}"
```

however, I am getting the followig error when executing the terrafrom script:

> The request content was invalid and could not be deserialized: 'Error
>   converting value
>   "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#"
>   to type
>   'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ResourceStack.Frontdoor.Data.Definitions.DeploymentParameterDefinition'.
>   Path 'properties.parameters.$schema', line 1, position 2952.'.

Below is the `params.json` file:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "apiVersion": {
            "value": "2017-06-01"
        },
        "sku": {
            "value": "Standard"
        "location": {
            "value": "westus"
        },
        "notificationSettings": {
            "value": {
                "notifyGlobalAdmins": "Enabled",
                "notifyDcAdmins": "Enabled",
                "additionalRecipients": []
            }
        },
        "subnetName": {
            "value": "xxxx"
        },
        "vnetName": {
            "value": "xxxx"
        },
        "vnetAddressPrefixes": {
            "value": [
                "10.0.1.0/24"
            ]
        },
        "subnetAddressPrefix": {
            "value": "10.0.1.0/24"
        },
        "nsgName": {
            "value": "xxxxx"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a way to pass arbitrary data structures from Terraform to ARM.

There are two ways to pass data to the ARM template within the azure_template_deployment provider

- use the `parameters` block, which is limited to string parameters only
- use the `parameters_body` block, which is pretty much arbitrary JSON.

I find the easiest way to use the parameters block is to create a local variable with the structure I require, then call `jsonencode` on it. I also like to keep the ARM template in a separate file and pull it in via a `file()` call, reducing the complexity of the terraform.

```
locals {
  location = "string"
  members = [
    "array",
    "of",
    "members"
  ]
  enabled = true
  tags = {
    "key" = "value",
    "simple" = "store"
  }

  # this is the format required by ARM templates
  parameters_body = {
    location = {
      value = "${local.location}"
    },
    properties = {
      value = {
        users = {
          members = "${local.members}"
        }
        boolparameter = "${local.enabled}"
      }
    }
    tags = {
      value = "${module.global.tags}"
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_template_deployment" "sample" {
  name = "sample"
  resource_group_name = "rg"
  deployment_mode = "Incremental"
  template_body = "${file("${path.module}/arm/sample_arm.json")}"
  parameter_body = "${jsonencode(local.parameters_body)}"
}
```

The only caveat I've found is that the bool parameters pass as a string, so declare them as a string in the ARM parameters section, then use a ARM function to convert to bool

```
"parameters: {
  "boolParameter": {
     "type": "string"
  }
},
"variables": {
  "boolVariable": "[bool(parameters('boolParameter'))]"
},
"resources": [
  ...
  "boolArm": "[variables('boolVariable')]",
  ...
]
```

Comment: instead of using locals, can I just give the entire `json` params to parameter_body similar to how you read file for template_body ? I have actually tried it but I am getting errors related to api versioning and schema

Comment: yes if there are no dynamic parts to your JSON just pull from the file system. You can also use a heredoc style inline.
See [Ivan Ignatiev](http://ivanignatiev.com/blog/technical-details/terraform-workaround-arm-deployment-parameters/) for his take, yours sounds simple.

Comment: Thank you, the article you have shared with me has helped to solve the problem. using locals would have been more lines of code and more complications. Would you be kind to update you answer please?

Comment: Update the answer how ? The article uses heredoc as well - you want an answer with heredoc and not locals ? Seems like a minor refactor.

Comment: @Leif   did you found another way to pass bool parameters? I am struggling now with numeric (integer) parameters and wonder if there is a nice way to define them in parameters section

Comment: ARM supports this "[int(parameters('intParameter')]"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-numeric#int