# Terraform - Using an ARM template to deploy Azure AD Domain Service (AADDS) using "azurerm_template_deployment"

Tags: json, terraform, azure-resource-manager

I am using a Terraform `azurerm_template_deployment` to deploy an AADDS and I get the below error when running `terraform apply`

```
Error: Error validating Template for Deployment "aadds-arm-template" (Resource Group "RG-VNET-Aadds-001"): Deployment template validation failed: 'Template parameter JToken type is not valid. Expected 'Array'. Actual 'String'. Please see https://aka.ms/resource-manager-parameter-files for usage details.'.
-----------------------------------
```

I use the construct below to pass the theparams.parameters.json and aadds-arm-template.json files in my terraform code:

```
resource "azurerm_template_deployment" "aadds-arm-template" {
    name                    = "aadds-arm-template"
    resource_group_name     = local.RG-Aadds-Name 
    template_body           = file("aadds-arm-template.json")
    parameters_body         = file("theparams.parameters.json")     
    deployment_mode = "Incremental" 
}
```

I believe Terraform is having a problem with this object construct:

```
        "notificationSettings": {
            "value": {
                "notifyGlobalAdmins": "Disabled",
                "notifyDcAdmins": "Enabled",
                "additionalRecipients": []
            }
        },
```

Which is in my `theparams.parameters.json` file I did not post the content of both the files as I am sure it is the passing of the object which is causing all the fuss. Would appreciate if someone would help. I have also used the same construct in this link: [Terraform - Passing type Object as a parameter to Azure Template Deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59920283/terraform-passing-type-object-as-a-parameter-to-azure-template-deployment) but it never worked.

I dont know what to do please help makes no sense I have working on resolving this for the passed 2 days.

Comment: Hey Egal, I see this is your first question so please read this article on how to ask a better question -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Typically people on this platform like seeing a little more about what effort you've put into solving the problem. While you may be frustrated with your issue, your question comes off a lot like "do my homework" and has very little information about your terraform module or what you've tried so far

Comment: You can edit your question to add additional information. It's not necessary to ask a new question unless you are changing the topic you are asking about.

Answer (score 0):

Your error output tells you what's wrong...

```
'Template parameter JToken type is not valid. Expected 'Array'. Actual 'String'. 
Please see https://aka.ms/resource-manager-parameter-files for usage details.'.
```

Fix that parameter to be an array.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to thank Leif: https://stackoverflow.com/users/739351/leif who posted this answer to someone else a while ago and finally got to get my code to work using the solution in his article here: [Terraform - Passing type Object as a parameter to Azure Template Deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59920283/terraform-passing-type-object-as-a-parameter-to-azure-template-deployment).

Great stuff thank you.
-egal